# Match query optimization for multiple nodes Neo4j

Tags: optimization, neo4j, graph-databases

I am running a query on 3 tables which are connected with the same id of an application. However, this query runs too long to get any result. How can I optimize this query? The application_id by which both edges are created should be the same for both Sms and Pcb nodes.

This is the query itself:

```
 MATCH (pcb:PhoneContactsBook)-[:APP_PCB]->(a:Applications)-[:APP_SMS]->(sms:Sms)
    RETURN distinct a.application_id
```

To get the query plan, I run this query with `LIMIT 200,000` and I get 1046648 total db hits in 1251 ms.

Here is the query plan:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to get the query plan, you can use `EXPLAIN` instead of `PROFILE` :

- `EXPLAIN` do not run the query and only give you the query plan of the query
- `PROFILE` executes the query, and give you the result of your query + its query plan

I don't see any optimization here, because you are asking the database to give you all the instance of a specific pattern and there is no where clause, no sub-statement, no aggregation ...

But it seems that **you have a lot instances of this pattern in your database** (more than 200 000), that's why this query takes some times (~6 microsecondes per pattern is not bad ^^)

Comment: Thanks for reminding about explain. I have updated my question with the query plan. Also, the essence of the query is to find applications which both have sms and phone contacts book. So the id of the application unites both entities

Comment: so you only need the `application_id` in your return ?

Comment: Yeah, unique application id, maybe some data about other entities. But it's not necessary